# On convergence of $ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{d x}{\left(x^{2}+1\right) \cdot \sin ^{2 / 3}(x)} $

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm d x}{\left(x^{2}+1\right) \cdot \sin ^{2 / 3}(x)}
$$
I want to study the convergence of this integral on a neighborhood of plus infinity, I mean starting the integration from $1$ for example. I thought about using cauchy criterion to say that it diverges but it seems that it converges and I don't see which criterion proves it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The map is not defined for $x \in \pi \mathbb N$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Both the Lebesgue integral and improper Riemann integral of $\frac1{x^{2/3}}$ on $[-1,1]$ exist.  The only concern is the sum of the integral over all singular points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Near $n\pi$, $|\sin^{2/3}(x)|\approx |x-n\pi|^{2/3}$ which is an integrable singularity.  The term $x^2+1$ insures the convergence of the integral, when all the singularity contributions are added up.